# SQL Server : group by sum of column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to aggregate data by one column which contains numeric data.

I have data like:

```
ID | Amount
---+-------
1  | 44
2  | 15
3  | 16
4  | 8
5  | 16
```

Result, which I expect is:

```
ID | Amount
---+-------
1  | 44
2  | 31
4  | 24
```

Query should group data ordered by `ID` column by `Amount` column in parts of max sum of amount 32. If amount is greater then 32 then it should be presented as one 'group'. Result should contain `Min(ID)` and `SUM(Amount)` which can't be greater than 32 when group more than one record.

Comment: sounds like you need to do this inside a cursor. Then write the values to a temp table

Comment: One set depends on the previous set. I don't think this can be done *just* SQL.

Comment: I'd love to know what you're actually trying to accomplish here. There must be a better way

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I know how to accomplish this is using iteration (although in your case if you have enough single values over 32, then you might be able to use a more efficient approach).

Iteration in SQL Server queries is handled by recursive CTEs (once you forswear cursors):

```
with v as (
      select *
      from (values (1, 44), (2, 15), (3, 16), (4, 8), (5, 16) ) v(id, amount)
     ),
     t as (
      select v.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
     ),
     cte as (
      select seqnum, id, amount, id as grp
      from t
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select t.seqnum, t.id,
             (case when t.amount + cte.amount > 32 then t.amount else t.amount + cte.amount end) as amount,
             (case when t.amount + cte.amount > 32 then t.id else cte.grp end) as grp
      from cte join
           t
           on cte.seqnum = t.seqnum + 1
     )
select grp, max(amount)
from cte
group by grp;
```

I should note that the use of `max(amount)` in the outer query assumes that the values are never negative.  A slight modification can handle that situation.

Also, the intermediate result using `t` is not strictly necessary for the data you have provided.  It ensures that the columns used in the `join` actually have no gaps.

Comment: the groups won't get assigned as required per this query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this version with rownumbers assigned initially and each row is joined to the previous one in a recursive cte. And if the running sum > 32 a new group starts.

```
with rownums as (select t.*,row_number() over(order by id) as rnum from t)
,cte(rnum,id,amount,runningsum,grp) as (select rnum,id,amount,amount,1  from rownums where rnum=1
                                        union all
                                        select t.rnum,t.id,t.amount
                                        ,case when c.runningsum+t.amount > 32 then t.amount else c.runningsum+t.amount end
                                        ,case when c.runningsum+t.amount > 32 then t.id else c.grp end
                                        from cte c
                                        join rownums t on t.rnum=c.rnum+1
                                      )
select grp as id,max(runningsum) as amount
from cte
group by grp
```

[**`Sample Demo`**](http://rextester.com/AZJMJ78439)